# Getting the contents of a 404 error page response ruby

Tags: ruby, nokogiri, open-uri

I know some languages have a library that allows you to get the HTTP content for a 404 or 500 message.

Is there a library that allows that for Ruby?

I've tried open-uri but it simply returns an HTTPError exception without the HTML content for the 404 response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't seem to be stated clearly enough in the docs, but HttpError has an io attribute, which you can treat as a read only file as far as i know.

```
require 'open-uri'

begin
  response = open('http://google.com/blahblah')
rescue => e
  puts e # Error message
  puts e.io.status # Http Error code
  puts e.io.readlines # Http response body
end
```

Comment: sweet! exactly what I was looking for. I wish they'd include this in the doc. I checked there and did not find this info (did find info on the status and the code tho)

Answer (score 4):

`Net::HTTP` supports what you need.

You can use the request_get method and it will return a response regardless of the status code.

From script/console:

```
> http = Net::HTTP.new('localhost', 3000)
=> #<Net::HTTP localhost:3000 open=false>
> resp = http.request_get('/foo') # a page that doesn't exist
=> #<Net::HTTPNotFound 404 Not Found readbody=true>
> resp.code
=> "404"
> resp.body
=> "<html>...</html>"
```

(If the library is not available to you by default, you can do a `require 'net/http'`

Comment: Sweet. Thanks Nick! Looks like Open-uri is a wrapper around Net::HTTP to make things simpler. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 3):

Works with HTTParty as well https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

HTTParty.get("http://google.com/blahblah").parsed_response
```

There are a number of HTTP Clients available, choose one you like from https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/http_clients